# Rails Form, How to set value of hidden field with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, hidden

in my  rails application in a view, i have  some input box

```
....
 <%= form.label :object_id %>
 <input type="text" id="bla" disabled="disabled">
 <%= form.hidden_field :object_id, id: :_id %>
....
```

with my Jquery script i tryed to set the value of the hidden field and it sets the right value, but when i submit the form to save it save something like that:

# < something :0x007f2331b74408>

Why?
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Is it saving the wrong value or are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hidden_field method has the following signature:

```
hidden_field(object_name, method, options = {})
```

Try setting it as follows:

```
<%= f.hidden_field 'object_id', :value => params[:object_id] %>
```

Right now, the value of the field is set to a reference of a object rather than the value.

Comment: Can you check the value of the params when it's being sent to the controller?

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: `puts #{params.inspect}` inside the controller method where this form is sending data.

Comment: i check the post request from the view to the controlled and it's right but it still save wrong value

Comment: If you are getting the right value from params then please check your controller code

Comment: ok i check the db value and the are right , sorry for the problem non problem